# Monogame 3.6 shared project intellisense not working in Monodevelop 7.5

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, monodevelop, monogame

I'm really new to Monodevelop and Monogame and I just installed elementary OS Linux (which I'm not all that new to Linux but I'm not a pro) and I got everything working. However, I was going to refactor my game project for crossplatform support and so I wanted to try out this new thing I read about called shared projects. Well when I tried it out, intellisense does not seem to be working for the monogame framework. Which kind of makes sense, how does it know where to find the library and what's in it if it's not referenced? So how is this supposed to work? I tried using a monogame shared library instead, but my monogame.extended addon didn't seem to wanna work with that. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to add the shared project to a real project that contained the references to Monogame and then everything works fine.